# The Sticky divs disappear when I open a dialogbox (only in Firefox)

Tags: angular, firefox, sticky

I have a front-end written in Angular. There I made my header sticky at top of screen.
So When I scroll the page the header stick on top of screen. The problem appears when I open a dialog box. If I didn't scroll the page than I will see my header but when I scroll the page and after that open the dialog-box than the header disappear as long as the dialog-box is open and after closing it, it is once again there. with other word the sticky feature doesn't work when the dialog-box is open.
This only happen with Firefox and not other browsers.
The feature: position: sticky; doesn't work for Firefox.
I wrote that you can fix it with this style: position: -webkit-sticky;
but didn't work.
I am using Angular 15.

this is the SCSS file:

```
shoppingCartWrapper {   position: sticky;   top: 130px; }
```

this is the typescript file where I call the Dialogbox:

```
  onCollapseClick(): void {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.data = {
      itemId: this.item.Id
    };
    dialogConfig.panelClass = "item-dialog";
    this.dialog.open(ItemDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
  }
```

and this is the html file:

```
<div> class="shoppingCartWrapper"> .... </div>
```

Comment: Provide code or a functional example in stackblitz.

Comment: It seems you need to specify top value and height value, please provide code for your problem.

Comment: DA and Ishan, I  updated the code!